# yaml: line 3: could not find expected ':' ERROR: failed to build: exit status 3

Tags: python-3.x, django, yaml, digital-ocean

I get this error trying to deploy my django project on digital ocean. I really have no clue what to o from here. I don't know what code to post here as is required, but I need help. Trying to google elsewhere, I don't get the much needed help.

```
yaml: line 3: could not find expected ':'  ERROR: failed to build: exit status 3
```

Comment: What yaml files do you have in your deployment thats probably the best place to start.

Comment: None, really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working after hours of struggling. I realized I was having a `Procfile` in my project which probably doesn't work with DO.
After deleting the Procfile, my app deployed successfully.